# No Views in web service project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got a web service project that runs and shows a webpage that is located in `Project_directory\Views\Home\Index.cshtml`.

I have created a simple web service, but when I run I get the following error:

[image]

How can I generate a Views directory in my project and get the system to load `Index.cshtml` ?

Comment: This structure belongs to asp.net mvc project convention where the default document is set in global.asax app_start event through asp.net mvc routing configuration.

Comment: a web _service_ is meant to be system->system, therefore the concept of a user-facing view is not relevant. If you want a user interface, create an MVC project.

Comment: In MVC, you don't navigate directly to a view. You enter a URL, which routes to an action method within a controller, that returns a view. You should never be entering `somepage.cshtml` into a URL in MVC.